# Native javascript date format in cookie value?

Tags: javascript, date, cookies

I have some code I'm refactoring where PHP sets the current date/time in a cookie. There is some javascript that parses the date from this string, and creates a javascript `Date` object from it.

However, the code is laborious. Since I have the opporuntity to re-write this, I would like to store the current date time in a format more amenable to javascript creating a `Date` object out of it.

What is the most efficient way to store the date as a string in a cookie for javascript to ingest, later on?

An important factor is that I need to include the timezone in this reckoning.

Comment: "Efficient"? Store it as the string rep, and create a new Date object from that string rep?

Comment: @DaveNewton -- there are a lot of different ways for format a date in a string. Can javascript just ingest "Monday, December 19th, 2016 11:54 AM EST"?

Comment: All _native_ JS date formats are listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Comment: @user151841 It would have been quicker to simply try it, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton if I had, I may never have arrived at the knowledge you imparted in your comment, that `Date` can parse its own string output. I would have gone on formatting dates to string, and then parsing them to be ingested afterwards.  I've never been let down by assuming myself to be over-engineering.

Comment: @user151841 But that's all I'm suggesting; you *are* formatting a date to a string, then parsing it when you pull it out--the `Date` docs state that the ctor takes a string input. I dunno, I guess I'm just in the habit of trying things first.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm a back-end developer. When I think of 'formatting a date', I think of php's `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`, where I specify exactly what format I want the date to be in. That's why I don't think I'm formatting anything when I do `console.log(date);`. I'm not fluent with javascript; when I try things out, I get syntax errors, unexpected results, and I bang my head against a wall until someone hands me a clue stick.

Comment: @hindmost—there is only one [*Date format*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format) specified in ECMA-262, all the others are implementation dependent and should not be relied on.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the cookie with the date as follows:

```
var today = new Date();
document.cookie = 'yourCookieName' + '=' + today
```

And then when you want to get the value and use it as a date object again just grab the cookie value:

```
var cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)yourCookieName\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
```

Once you have the string value of the date you set, just use it as follows:

```
var anotherDate = new Date(cookieValue);
```

anotherDate will be a date object from the cookie date string.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I can use `Date.parse()` to get a unix timestamp from the string version of a `Date` object.

Since I'm using JQuery's cookie library, here's what I've done:

```
$.cookie('arrival',
  new Date(),
  { expires : 30,
    path    : '/',
    domain  : 'my domain.com' }
);
```

And to read it:

```
var cookieDate = new Date(Date.parse($.cookie('arrival')));
```

Comment: You don't even need that: `Date` can parse its own string output.

Comment: @DaveNewton care to make that an answer?

Comment: If you want the date string to be exchangeable, use `new Date.toISOString()`. Then you can do `new Date('arrival')` wherever.