# Is it possible to call a function after a specifc time?

Tags: reactjs

For example is it possible to call a function after 2 weeks?
I thought about react and a library like dayjs and some code like this:

```
const date = Number(dayjs(new Date()).format("DD"))
if (date === date + 14) {
    //function
}
```

I testet it with seconds and realised that i am dumb because everytime i refresh the page it will restart the "timer". Do you have any ideas if it is possible?

Comment: Use a cookie, with the value being either the start time or the end time.  On page load you can test if that cookie exists.  if it exists, see if it's time to do whatever you want to do.  If it doesn't, create it. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227385/native-javascript-date-format-in-cookie-value/41227618

Comment: This sounds like you need a backend job system to handle certain jobs at certain times, otherwise, although you set the function to be executed after 2 weeks, it will not be executed if the page is not visited at that time.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you could make a cookie/session storage item containing the date at which you want this to take place. Here is an example using session storage, though a cookie is more preferable:

```js
const nowInTwoWeeks = new Date(Date.now()) // Today's date
nowInTwoWeeks.setDate(nowInTwoWeeks.getDate() + 14) // Add 14 days

sessionStorage.setItem('twoWeeksMark', nowInTwoWeeks)

const now = new Date(Date.now()) // Today's date to use for comparison

if (now >= sessionStorage.getItem('twoWeeksMark')) {
  // Do the work
}
```